# How to remove $\log(e)$ from output in Maxima?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

I'm learning Maxima (wxMaxima) at the moment and I let it calculate the Laplace transform of $f(t) = e^{-2t}\cos{(3t)}$, so I ran

```
laplace(e^(-2*t)*cos(3*t),t,s);
```

which gave back $${{s+2\,\log e}\over{s^2+4\,\log e\,s+4\,\log ^2e+9}}$$ (when displayed in $\TeX$ form).

Since $\log{e} = 1$, how can I remove those $\log{e}$'s from the output? My guess is that Maxima doesn't recognize $e$ automatically as Euler's number.

(Side question: Apparently Maxima uses $\log{x}$ for $\log_e{x}$, not $\ln{x}$, can this be changed?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maxima the constant $e$ is represented by the command `%e`.

$\pi$ and $i$ are similar represented by `%pi` and `%i` respectively.

Comment: Or by E, or Exp[1].